# Ao chamado o metodo de update, o laravel não reconhece a rota

Tags: php, laravel

Sou iniciante com **laravel(5.5)** e estou com um problema. Criei um *crud* de *products*, consigo lista-lo e visualizar o registro, porém quando eu tento fazer um update, ele me retorna um erro:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException

### BLADE:

```
@extends('base')
@section('main')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2">
        <h1 class="display-3">Update a product</h1>

        @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
        <br />
        @endif
        <form method="post" action="{{ route('products.update', $product->id) }}">
            @method('PATCH')
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value={{ $product->name }} />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="description">Description:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" value={{ $product->description }} />
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity" value={{ $product->quantity }} />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="price">Price:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price" value={{ $product->price }} />
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

### CONTOLLER:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\ProductRequest;
use App\Product;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
        return view('products.index',['products' => $products]);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('products.create');
    }

    public function store(ProductRequest $request)
    {
        $product = new Product;
        $product->name        = $request->name;
        $product->description = $request->description;
        $product->quantity    = $request->quantity;
        $product->price       = $request->price;
        $product->save();
        return redirect()->route('products.index')->with('message', 'Product created successfully!');
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
        return view('products.edit',compact('product'));
    }

    public function update(ProductRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
        $product->name        = $request->name;
        $product->description = $request->description;
        $product->quantity    = $request->quantity;
        $product->price       = $request->price;
        $product->save();
        return redirect()->route('products.index')->with('message', 'Product updated successfully!');
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
        $product->delete();
        return redirect()->route('products.index')->with('alert-success','Product hasbeen deleted!');
    }
}
```

### ROUTES

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

// Route::resource('products', 'ProductController')->middleware('auth');
Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');
```

Comment: Pesquisando descobri que pode ter haver com o @csrf.
Tentei usar tambem o {{ csrf_field() }}
Mas nada tambem

Comment: Cara, vc ja tentou tirar esse cara aqui do blade @method('PATCH'), o formulário tem o metodo e acho que o laravel consegue entender o metodo update sem isso.

Answer (score 0):

**Funcionamento dos CRUDs do Laravel**

A exceção "**MethodNotAllowedHttpException**" é disparada quando uma invocação é feita para uma rota cujo método (POST, GET, PUT/PATH, DELETE) não foi especificado corretamente.

Por exemplo, suponha que você declare uma rota assim:

```
Route::get('products', 'ProductController');
```

Se você invocá-la com **form method="post" action="{{ route('products') }}"**, a exceção será disparada, pois não existe uma rota **POST** para "products".

**Seu problema**

Segundo a [documentação do Laravel 5.5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers), é necessário usar PATCH ou PUT para invocar uma rota ".update" em um CRUD.

Para isso ser feito, existem duas maneiras:

1. Criar no formulário um campo **input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH"**;
2. Usar um helper para isso, no caso **{{ method_field('PATCH') }}**.

O problema é que você está usando a diretiva @method('PATCH') do Blade.

**Mas a diretiva @method só está disponível no Laravel 5.6 ou superior**.

Como a sua versão é 5.5, então deve usar o helper **{{ method_field('PATCH') }}** no lugar.

```html
<form method="post" action="{{ route('products.update', $product->id) }}">

    {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
    
    @csrf
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value={{ $product->name }} />
    </div>
    
    ....
```

Comment: Ótimo, fiz exatamente, e ele passou da rota, porém de alguma forma não encontra o request: segue o erro:

ReflectionException
Class App\Http\Requests\ProductRequest does not exist.

O mesmo ocorre ao tentar criar.
Ao tentar remover o registro, funciona normalmente

Comment: O disparo de MethodNotAllowedHttpException foi resolvido. Esse é um outro problema... tente revisar a localização da classe ProductRequest e se o namespace dentro dela está correto. Problemas de Reflection significam que o Laravel não encontrou a classe que você especificou no Controller.

Comment: Por algum motivo esta classe não estava criada realmente, agora resolveu.
Obrigado